# How to move batches of files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I have a folder with 1092 files. I need to move those files to a new directory in batches of 10 (each new folder will have only 10 files each, so max. of 110 folders).

I tried this code, and now the folders have been created, but I can't find any of original files (???). They are neither in the original and newly created folders...

```
path = "/home/user/Documents/MSc/Imagens/Dataset"
paths = []

for root, dirs, file in os.walk(path):
    for name in file:
        paths.append(os.path.join(root,name))

start = 0
end = 10

while end <= 1100:
    dest = str(os.mkdir("Dataset_" + str(start) + "_" + str(end)))
    for i in paths[start:end]:
        shutil.move(i, dest)
    start += 10
    end += 10
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you. If there are still problems you might consider leaving a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your `move` command, you are moving all 10 files to one single folder - but not **into** that folder as the filenames are missing. And `dest` is none, since `os.mkdir()` doesn't return anything.

You need to append the filename to `dest`:

```
dataset_dirname = "Dataset_" + str(start) + "_" + str(end)
os.mkdir(dataset_dirname)
dataset_fullpath = os.path.join(path, dataset_dirname)
for i in paths[start:end]:
    # append filename to dataset_fullpath and move the file
    shutil.move(i, os.path.join(dataset_fullpath , os.path.basename(i)))
```